# Why do we say fear God because of the Benefits? Shouldnt it be Leshem Shomayim

Tags: tehilim-psalms, reward-punishment, middos-character-traits, pirke-avot-ethicsof, kedusha-holiness

It says (Tehilim 34:10):

> יראו את ה' קדושיו כי אין מחסור ליראיו

Why do we tell the holy ones to fear God because they will lack nothing? The Mishnah (Avos 1:3) says one should serve God without intending to receive reward. Obviously, not everyone is on that level, as the Tosafos Yom Tov explains there, but I would have thought the קדושיו that are mentioned are on that level?

Answer (score 2):

[The Radak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=120) explains that קדושיו  refers to the ascetics of the world, just like a nazir is called "kadosh" for being an ascetic (similar to the language of נזיר אחיו "[Yosef] elevated over his brothers" (ba)). He is telling them not to fear that they will run out of things to feed themselves — fear only G-d.